# Обрезать белый фон на картинке средствами PHP

Tags: php, изображения, gd

Есть задача обрезать фото по краям изображения, чтобы не было белых пустых областей (только рабочая область). Первое, что приходит на ум - разбирать изображение и выборочно проверять пиксели из областей по краям до появления пикселей с цветом отличным от белого. Далее выполнять обрезку по найденным таким образом строкам и столбцам.

Как можно это задачу выполнить более простым способом? Есть ли готовые библиотеки/функции для такой обрезки? Крайне желательно, чтобы они были устойчивы к шуму и правильно выполняли ресайз фотографии в наибольшем проценте случаев.

P.S. Пример исходного изображения: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCrAn.jpg

Comment: Пример исходного изображения, если кто-то захочет ответить конкретным кодом - ему самому придумывать? Нельзя ли в вопрос добавить?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov добавил. но в целом это универсальная задача, выполнить ресайз по белым полям любого изображения.

Comment: @Dmitry Maslennikov, но jpg не имеет альфа-каналов для прозрачности, обычно для таких целей используют png, apng, gif...

Comment: @And причем здесь альфа-канал? задача не вырезать полностью изображение из фона, а выполнить его ресайз (убрать пустые белые поля сверху/снизу/слева/справа). делается чисто для эстетики, чтобы в каталоге не было разнобоя.

Comment: @Dmitry Maslennikov, не сразу понял вопрос, но я понял, что не какой-то фон или поля, а отступы по краям.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ответ**

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecropauto.php

```
$cropped_img_white = imagecropauto($original_img , IMG_CROP_THRESHOLD, null, 16777215);
// or
$cropped_img_white = imagecropauto($original_img , IMG_CROP_WHITE);
```

**Как я бы делал с нуля.**

Допустим есть изображение **A** x **B**.
A - Ширина.
В - Высота.

1. Скопировать
2. Преобразовать  в черно-белое. Так же можно уменьшить изображение в 2/3/4 ... раза.(Ненужные данные.)
3. Попробовать немного повысить контраст/яркость(необязательно, надо пробовать)
4. Преобразовать/resize в изображение с высотой в 1 пиксель. Картинка будет **А** х **1**.(Можно написать самому, можно попробовать разные алгоримы сжатия).
5. Слева и права считаем пиксели которые "белые" с учетом погрешности(Константу погрешности надо подбирать).
6. Обрезаем оригинал до полученных значений. (Если изображение уменьшали на шаге 2 не забываем умножить)
7. ???
8. **Profit**